# Mouseover on child element, not on parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I'm implementing a highlight feature, which highlights the current hovered div and i have html structure something like this:

```
<div> <!-- this is the parent -->
    <div> content ... </div><!-- a child -->
    <div> content ... </div><!-- another child-->
</div>
```

how it should work:
  - if i hover over the parent, then it should highlight the parent element.
  - if i hover over a child element, the parent element's highlighting should fade and it should only highlight the child element

i'm using jquerys' mouseenter and mouseleaves events for that, the code looks like this
(actually its a bit different because im working with gwt and the native javascript interface, but it works the same way):

```
$(element).mouseenter(function(event)
{
    showHighlightContainer();
});

$(element).mouseleave(function(event)
{
    hideHighlightContainer();
});
```

the problem is: when i hover over the parent element, the element is beeing highlighted and everything is fine.
but when i hover over a child element, the child elemend AND the parent element are highlighted.

am i using the wrong mouse events? how could i solve that?

Comment: try to use `this` in your function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use mouseover and mouseout

```
$(element).mouseover(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    showHighlightContainer();
}).mouseout(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    hideHighlightContainer();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7xbXz/)

Comment: event.stopPropagation() is what was fcking with me, thanks!